# What problems could arise from having a model called 'Set'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, naming, naming-conventions

I'm coming up with names for some of my models, and am hesitating on the word 'set'.

The rails app is mostly concerned with managing trading cards, which are traditionally grouped by release into sets.

However, I know that the word set is used as a method name for some objects (iirc, to atomically assign a value to a field of a model).

Would it be OK to use 'Set' for a model's name, or should I find an alternative? Are there any collisions I should be aware of?

Comment: If a simple rename to `CardSet` removes any ambiguity then why not?

Comment: I want to avoid cases like: card.set(:cardset, cardset), although that's not much better than card.set(:set, set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Set` is actually the name of one of [Ruby's default classes](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html), sensibly enough describing Sets. I would avoid naming a class after this since you'll clobber the default Set implementation which some libraries might theoretically make use of.

You can still name a method on a class `set`, though. I don't think that's taken by anything.

Comment: thanks, this is basically exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb it's better to use name for your classes different from reserved name or name defined in the framework. It may work well in the beginning but after few month or years you may run into problems (that would be very hard to debug, due to name collision) and it will be very hard to refactorize your classes.

AMHA you should use some other name

Comment: ahaha :) can't hide anymore